# Hide the same values after a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some values in `span`s of class `hi` and `hello`, and they have some similarities. For example, `h1_2` and `h1_4` are present in both `span`s. How would I go about hiding the duplicates in `hello` (`hi_2` and `hi_4`) on button click?

```js
$('.click').live('click', function () {
    var val_sp = $(".hi b").map(function () {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();
    //if (.hello == val_sp) {
        $('.hello').text(val_sp).hide()
    //};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click</button><p>

<span class="hi">
 <b>hi_1</b>
 <b>hi_2</b>
 <b>hi_3</b>
 <b>hi_4</b>
</span>
    
<span class="hello">    
 <b>hello_1</b>
 <b>hi_2</b>
 <b>hello_3</b>
 <b>hi_4</b>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this (going by the title of your question).

```
$(".click").click(function(){
   $(".hi b").each(function(){
      $(".hello b:contains("+$(this).text()+")").hide();
   });
});
```

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zxkcr/)**

Comment: +1 - exactly what I was building if jsfiddle would friggin' load!

Comment: Yup, fiddle is freaking slow at times.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is answer you wanted

http://jsfiddle.net/yyTH8/7/

```
$('.click').live('click', function () {
    $(".hi b").each(function(a,b){
        $(".hello:contains("+$(this).html()+")").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: It looks like he wants to hide duplicate items, but I can hardly understand it.

Comment: @pimvdb: yes, I do not understand him either